# Why does this GRPC Client suggest I install this golang package twice?

Tags: go, installation, grpc

According to https://github.com/vadimi/grpc-client-cli, I should execute two `go install` commands to install this package, the first with a particular version number, and the second with `latest`.

What is the purpose of having two commands, and how does it differ from merely installing the latest version?

```
For go 1.17+ use this command to install the app to $GOPATH/bin directory:

    go install github.com/vadimi/grpc-client-cli/cmd/grpc-client-cli@v1.16.0
    go install github.com/vadimi/grpc-client-cli/cmd/grpc-client-cli@latest
```

Comment: I think you should raise an issue.  That looks weird.  Either it is a mistake, or the documentation should explain why they are doing this.  Note that "v1.16.0" and "latest" are the same thing.

Comment: Likely it's intended as "or" not as "and".